# Windows photos app - not able to navigate through the photos

Tags: windows-10, photos

If I open any photo using the Photos application in Windows 10 OS then I am able to click on the left/right arrows on the keyboard to move to the next photos. But incase I zoom-in in any of the photos and then zoom out, then I am not able to navigate to other photos anymore. I need to close the window and open again

How to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that pressing CTRL+0 would make arrows appear again and you will be able to navigate to the next photos

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-photos-app-not-able-to-navigate-through/ed7b7931-462e-44dc-8112-6faa106749f6